# create a macro variable to store all variable names of a dataset

Tags: sas

I'm a beginner in sas. 
I have a data set work.data2 with variables that include all variables from another dataset work.data1.

here is what I want to do:

```
data temp;
    set data2 (keep = [list of all variables in data1] key2 key3);
run;
```

First I need to create a macro variable to store all variable names in data1.
if it's in python i can just do

```
List=list(data1)
```

but it seems much harder to realize in sas...Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?  Perhaps there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of way to get lists of variable names into data.  You could use PROC CONTENTS with OUT= option.  Or query the DICTIONARY.COLUMNS metadata from PROC SQL. (or the view SASHELP.VCOLUMN that points to the same metadata).

But here is a method that does not require pulling the names.  First make an empty new dataset with the same structure as DATA1 plus your extra variables.  Then append the data from DATA2.

```
data temp;
  set data1(obs=0) data2(obs=0 keep=key1 key2);
run;
proc append base=temp data=data2 force;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, it solves my problem at the moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to skin this cat.  Here's one method:

Assuming all of the variables names are stored in a variable (column) called `Data2Var` in `work.data2`, then this should work:

```
proc sql noprint;
select Data2Var into: VarList separated by " "
from
work.data1;
quit;

data work.temp;
set work.data2(KEEP = &VarList key1 key2);
run;
```

Basically what this is doing is that the first `proc sql` block of code creates a macro variable that consists of every value in the column `Data2Var` from your `work.data1` dataset and separates the values by spaces.  This macro variable (`&Data2Var`) is then called on your keep statement when reading in the `data2` dataset.  The resulting dataset, `work.temp` then consists only of those values from the `work.data1` column `Data2Var` and `key1` and `key2`.

Comment: Thank you! it's what I was looking for, but first I need to create a variable in my dataset to store all variable names... i'm researching about it, please kindly advice if you know how to do it. thanks!! :)

Comment: Hi, I found out how to prepare the data before using your code. Thank you!

`proc contents data = work.data1
out = vars_list(keep = varnum name)
noprint;
run; 

proc sql noprint;
select distinct name
into :list1 separated by ' '
from vars_list
order by varnum;
quit;`